# Cross dependency issue with Google Collection and Google Guava on Shrinkwrap-resolver

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I'm dealing with the development of a **Java EE** project that involves several tools such as **jBPM**, **Hibernate**, **Resteasy**, ect.

In order to manage dependencies, I'm using Maven: my `pom.xml` is available **[here](http://pastebin.com/gDdjDCtn)**.

Now, I'd like to use inside that project **QueryDSL** `3.4.3` that depends on **Google Guava** `14.0.1`: unfortunately, something imports as dependency **Google Collections** `1.0` that generates a conflict with **Google Guava** `14.0.1`.

1. Is it possible to understand where Google Collections is from?
2. Is there a way to resolve this issue safety? (Now, I'm just removing  Google Collections's jar from the deployment folder)

---

### Update

By using the command `mvn dependency:tree`, I found that **Google Collections** `1.0` comes from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now, I've just to understand if it will work well also by excluding `google-collections`.

- See also: **[http://grepcode.com/.../shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven/2.1.1/](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven/2.1.1/)**

Comment: The command `mvn dependency:tree` should tell you where it's coming from.

Comment: When you figure out where the dependency that you want to remove is coming from, you then use <dependency>...<exclusions><exclusion><groupId>...</groupId><artifactId>...</artifactId></exclusion></exclusions></dependency> in the dependency that is pulling in the offending jar to exclude it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, **Google Collection** dependency comes from `shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven`.

I resolved that issue by editing the `pom.xml` as follows:

```
<!-- ShrinkWrap Maven Resolver for Arquillian Tests -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Then:

```
<!-- Arquillian profiles -->
<profiles>
    <!-- Arquillian test profile managed by JBoss AS 7 -->
    <profile>
        <id>arquillian-jbossas-managed</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
                            <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now, it works fine.